# Overloading operator= between objects of more than two classes

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I'm defining three classes for my application: `int2_` (couples of integers), `float2_` (couples of floats) and `double2_` (couples of doubles), essentially to perform complex arithmetics operations.

I want to overload the assignment `=` operator between objects of the above three classes. The motivation is that I'm writing a CUDA code, but it seems that there is no assignment operator already defined for the CUDA classes `int2`, `float2` and `double2`.

My current implementation is the following:

```
class int2_ {

    public:
        int x;
        int y;

        int2_() : x(), y() {}

        // Stuff
        const int2_& operator=(const float2_ a)     { int2_ b;  b.x = (int)a.x;             b.y = (int)a.y;     return b; }
        const int2_& operator=(const double2_ a)    { int2_ b;  b.x = (int)a.x;             b.y = (int)a.y;     return b; }
};

class float2_ {

    public:
        float x;
        float y;

        float2_() : x(), y() {}

        // Stuff
        const float2_& operator=(const double2_ a)  { float2_ b;    b.x = (float)a.x;       b.y = (float)a.y;   return b; }
};

class double2_ {

    public:
        double x;
        double y;

        double2_() : x(), y() {}

        // Stuff
};
```

Everything is summarized as *stuff* does not provide compilation errors. The remaining operator overloads return the following errors

```
error : identifier "float2_" is undefined
error : identifier "double2_" is undefined  
error : identifier "double2_" is undefined
```

respectively for the three different overloads.

It seems that there is a "visibility" problem due to the fact that, for example, `float2_` and `double2_` are not yet defined before the `int2_` class definition. Any suggestion on how solving the problem? Thank you very much in advance.

**SOLUTION FOLLOWING THE ANSWERS OF JAMES KANZE AND ALEXRIDER**

Here is the solution:

```
class int2_;
class float2_;
class double2_;

class int2_ {

    public:
        int x;
        int y;

        int2_() : x(), y() {}

        inline const int2_& operator=(const int a)          { x = a;            y = 0.;         return *this; }
        inline const int2_& operator=(const float a)        { x = (int)a;       y = 0.;         return *this; }
        inline const int2_& operator=(const double a)       { x = (int)a;       y = 0.;         return *this; }
        inline const int2_& operator=(const int2_ a)        { x = a.x;          y = a.y;        return *this; }
        inline const int2_& operator=(const float2_ a);
        inline const int2_& operator=(const double2_ a);
};

class float2_ {

    public:
        float x;
        float y;

        float2_() : x(), y() {}

        inline const float2_& operator=(const int a)        { x = (float)a;     y = 0.;         return *this; }
        inline const float2_& operator=(const float a)      { x = a;            y = 0.;         return *this; }
        inline const float2_& operator=(const double a) { x = (float)a;     y = 0.;         return *this; }
        inline const float2_& operator=(const int2_ a)      { x = (float)a.x;   y = (float)a.y; return *this; }
        inline const float2_& operator=(const float2_ a)    { x = a.x;          y = a.y;        return *this; }
        inline const float2_& operator=(const double2_ a);
};

class double2_ {

    public:
        double x;
        double y;

        double2_() : x(), y() {}

        inline const double2_& operator=(const int a)       { x = (double)a;    y = 0.;         return *this; }
        inline const double2_& operator=(const float a) { x = (double)a;    y = 0.;         return *this; }
        inline const double2_& operator=(const double a)    { x = a;            y = 0.;         return *this; }
        inline const double2_& operator=(const int2_ a) { x = (double)a.x;  y = (double)a.y;return *this; }
        inline const double2_& operator=(const float2_ a)   { x = (double)a.x;  y = (double)a.y;return *this; }
        inline const double2_& operator=(const double2_ a)  { x = a.x;          y = a.y;        return *this; }

};

        inline const int2_& int2_::operator=(const float2_ a)       { x = (int)a.x;             y = (int)a.y;       return *this; }
        inline const int2_& int2_::operator=(const double2_ a)      { x = (int)a.x;             y = (int)a.y;       return *this; }
        inline const float2_& float2_::operator=(const double2_ a)  { x = (float)a.x;           y = (float)a.y;     return *this; }
```

Comment: In the class int2_, your types float2_, double2_ are not defined yet. To use them, before class int2 declaration insert "class float2_; class double2_;" and instead of instance, pass references as arguments of operators. Read more in Forward declaration.

Comment: @Serhly  They're not even declared.  But I think he knows that; I think that's what he means by a "visibility" problem.

Comment: @Serhiyi Thanks Serhiyi, I'm already aware of that. Therefore I mentioned there is a "visibility" problem. Anyway, I modified my post to be more specific.

Comment: class int2_;
class float2_;
class double2_;
Is actually redundant, everything will work even without that.

Comment: @alexrider Are your sure? Removing those forward declaration, the code does not compile.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/v0TWO$0 compiles fine here, thru if there is something else in actual code, forward declaration may help. But I cant tell for sure without seeing that.

Comment: Sorry my fault, missed additional lines. Yes you need forward declarations, first one is still redundant thru.

Comment: @alexrider Yes, on this you are right. The first one is redundant. The others are necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use forward declarations of the classes:

```
class Int2;
class Float2;
class Double2;
```

Then, in the classes, you should only declare the functions, not
implement them.  The implementations should come after all of
the class definitions, either in a separate source file, or
explicitly declared inline.

Comment: Thank you very much. That suggestion worked. I edited my post to illustrate the final solution. One question: what do you mean by "inline"? Should I inline the operator `=`, or do you just mean "in the same file"? Again, thanks.

Comment: @JackOLantern When you have the implementation in the class, it will normally be inlined by the compiler; especially with small functions like this, the compiler will _not_ generate a function call, but simply generate the equivalent code in line.  In order to do this, the implemention must be visible (with most compilers); if the implementation is not in the class definition, you must declare it `inline` if you want to put it in the header file.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the `inline` keyword to my final solution. I think that if it is not necessary it will be simply ignored by the compiler, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change order of your classes declaration as following.
Forward declaration won't help in this case, since you need type to be declared to be used in operator=

```
class double2_ {

    public:
        double x;
        double y;

        double2_() : x(), y() {}

        // Stuff
};

class float2_ {

    public:
        float x;
        float y;

        float2_() : x(), y() {}

        // Stuff
        const float2_& operator=(const double2_ a)  { float2_ b;    b.x = (float)a.x;       b.y = (float)a.y;   return b; }
};


class int2_ {

    public:
        int x;
        int y;

        int2_() : x(), y() {}

        // Stuff
        const int2_& operator=(const float2_ a)     { int2_ b;  b.x = (int)a.x;             b.y = (int)a.y;     return b; }
        const int2_& operator=(const double2_ a)    { int2_ b;  b.x = (int)a.x;             b.y = (int)a.y;     return b; }
};
```

Also there is a problem with operator= itself, it should return *this; instead of b that will go out of scope right after operator= does it's job.

Comment: I could not reverse the order of class declaration because, for example, for the `double2_` class, "stuff" contains assignments between `double2_` and `int2_` and `float2_` also: I should have mentioned that before. Therefore, your suggestion does not solve the problem. But I appreciate the recommendation of returning `*this`, which is very important to make multiple assignments, e.g., `a=b=c;`. I edited my post with the final solution which incorporates also your suggestion. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `float2_` is defined only after `int2_`, where it is already used.
Add a forward declaration of these two classes and you should be fine:

```
class int2_;
class double2_;
```

Comment: Not if he keeps the implementation in the class definition.  In the implementation of the functions, he needs to see the complete class definition.

Comment: I added forward declarations as you suggested: `class int2_;`, `class float2_;`, and `class double2_;`, before the code I exposed in my post. Unfortunately, all the three errors now became `incomplete type is not allowed`.