# Overloading casting operator() between C++ real types and customized complex types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm defining three classes for my application: `int2_` (couples of integers), `float2_` (couples of floats) and `double2_` (couples of doubles), essentially to perform complex arithmetics operations.

After the discussions below:

[Discussion1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992461/overloading-operator-between-objects-of-more-than-two-classes)

and

[Discussion2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011774/overloading-operator-between-customized-classes-int2-float2-and-double2-for)

I implemented the following solution

```
class float2_;
class double2_;

class int2_ {

    public:
        int x;
        int y;

        __host__ __device__ int2_() : x(), y() {}

        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const int a)          { x = a;            y = 0.;             return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const float a)        { x = (int)a;       y = 0.;             return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const double a)       { x = (int)a;       y = 0.;             return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const int2_ a)        { x = a.x;          y = a.y;            return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const float2_ a);
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const double2_ a);

};

class float2_ {

    public:
        float x;
        float y;

        __host__ __device__ float2_() : x(), y() {}

        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const int a)        { x = (float)a;     y = 0.;             return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const float a)      { x = a;            y = 0.;             return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const double a)     { x = (float)a;     y = 0.;             return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const int2_ a)      { x = (float)a.x;   y = (float)a.y;     return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const float2_ a)    { x = a.x;          y = a.y;            return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const double2_ a);

};

class double2_ {

    public:
        double x;
        double y;

        __host__ __device__ double2_() : x(), y() {}

        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const int a)       { x = (double)a;    y = 0.;             return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const float a)     { x = (double)a;    y = 0.;             return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const double a)    { x = a;            y = 0.;             return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const int2_ a)     { x = (double)a.x;  y = (double)a.y;    return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const float2_ a)   { x = (double)a.x;  y = (double)a.y;    return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const double2_ a)  { x = a.x;          y = a.y;            return *this; }

};

__host__ __device__ inline const int2_& int2_::operator=(const float2_ a)       { x = (int)a.x;     y = (int)a.y;       return *this; }
__host__ __device__ inline const int2_& int2_::operator=(const double2_ a)      { x = (int)a.x;     y = (int)a.y;       return *this; }
__host__ __device__ inline const float2_& float2_::operator=(const double2_ a)  { x = (float)a.x;   y = (float)a.y;     return *this; }
```

which correctly defines all the possible assignments between `int`, `float`, `double` and `int2_`, `float2_` and `double2_`.

I would now like to overload the casting `()` operator. In order to overload, for example, the casting from `int` to `float2_`, I added the following line to the `float2_` class

```
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator()(const int in)  { x = (float)in; y=0.; return *this; };
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to have an effect. If I try

```
float2_ a;
int b = 1;
a = (float2_)b;
```

the compiler says

```
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "float2_"
```

Should I implement a wrapper class, say `int_`, to allow this kind of casting? Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with [std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: I'm dealing with CUDA programming, which defines the `int2`, `float2` and `double2` types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not overloading the cast operator, but the `()` operator. This is, you are defining an operator that should be used this way:

```
float2_ a;
float2_ b = a(3); // This is the operator you are overloading
```

Now, you cannot define a cast operator from a built-in type (such as `int`), but you can define an explicit constructor, which will provide the same functionality, more or less:

```
class float2_
{
public:
  //...
  float2_(int in) { x = (float)in; y=0. };
}
```

Using it:

```
float2_ f;
f = float2_(3); // Or directly float2_ f (3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You say that I cannot define a cast operator from a built-in type (such as `int`). Would it mean that I should use a "wrapper class", like for example `int_`? Thanks again.

Comment: @JackOLantern I think it is much easier to just define a constructor as I do in my example. The constructor works more or less as the cast operator would.

Comment: Definitely. That is exactly what I have already done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have overloaded `operator()` taking an `int` and returning a `float2_&`. You would use that like so:

```
float2_ a;
a(5); // Returns a float2_&
```

Instead, it sounds like you want a conversion operator. They have the form `operator type()` (note that there's no return type). So if you want to convert from a `float2_` to an `int`, you need the following inside the class definition

```
operator int() { /* Convert to int and return here */ }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I would need a conversion from `int` to `float2_`, not from `float2_` to `int`. Is it possible to achieve it without a "wrapper class" like `int_`? Thanks again.